# Why won't Docker Desktop in Windows launch properly?

Tags: windows, docker, desktop

The cache memory was loaded up with docker files (about 20 GB) so I used the Treesize tool to erase them, because it filled the memory of my laptop.
In the meantime, I downloaded podman for some other reasons.

Then, when I tried to open the Docker Desktop, I got this error:

```
"Something went wrong: Setting up docker api proxy listener: open\\.\pipe\docker-engine: Access is denied."
```

I had 3 options: *Quit, Diagnose & Feedback, Reset Docker to factory defaults.*

When I chose the latter option, then the docker Desktop tried to launch, but failed yet again with the following error message:

```
the factory reset could not be completed succesfully: clening up distro podman-machine-default, output: running [-d ~/.docker ] &&rm -rf ~/.docker in podman-machine-default: non-zero exit code 1
```

I tried to uninstall Docker Desktop and reinstall it, but I have the same issue.
I also uninstalled podman, in case that app was somehow relevant to the problem, but the problem persists. What can I possibly do?